# MySQL 8.0.17 memory usage increases until it crashes

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a database with 1.3m records, my VPS has 4GM memory and 4GB swap, MySQL memory usage keeps on increasing until it goes OOM and gets killed. here are my my.cnf:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1500M
innodb_log_file_size = 192M
innodb_buffer_pool_Instances = 1
join_buffer_size = 512k
max_heap_table_size = 32M
```

And this is my show engine innodb status result:

```
=====================================
2019-10-24 10:52:15 0x7f28e422f700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 0 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 10 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 101 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 0
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 1744
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 1815
RW-shared spins 490, rounds 1238, OS waits 751
RW-excl spins 263, rounds 16740, OS waits 566
RW-sx spins 0, rounds 0, OS waits 0
Spin rounds per wait: 2.53 RW-shared, 63.65 RW-excl, 0.00 RW-sx
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 116283041
Purge done for trx's n:o < 116282630 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 0
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421288749931536, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749930672, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749928944, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749928080, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749927216, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749926352, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749925488, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749924624, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749923760, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749922896, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421288749922032, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
19598 OS file reads, 658 OS file writes, 475 OS fsyncs
12000.00 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 18494, seg size 18496, 0 merges
merged operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
discarded operations:
insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 963 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 0 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1225 buffer(s)
Hash table size 34679, node heap has 1 buffer(s)
3252000.00 hash searches/s, 207000.00 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number          96484013859
Log buffer assigned up to    96484013859
Log buffer completed up to   96484013859
Log written up to            96484013859
Log flushed up to            96484013859
Added dirty pages up to      96484013859
Pages flushed up to          96484013859
Last checkpoint at           96484013859
203 log i/o's done, 0.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 137363456
Dictionary memory allocated 498490
Buffer pool size   8192
Free buffers       1
Database pages     6002
Old database pages 2196
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      1
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 3594, not young 4709168
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 19545, created 141, written 263
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 999 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 712 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 6002, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[4169]:cur[74], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
1 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=9882, Main thread ID=139813261874944 , state=sleeping
Number of rows inserted 9, updated 315, deleted 0, read 154484
0.00 inserts/s, 0.00 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 0.00 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

And this is my journactl for when it crashes:

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-10-05 09:39:17 +08, end at Thu 2019-10-24 10:57:54 +08. --
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: 4335 total pagecache pages
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: 353 pages in swap cache
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: Swap cache stats: add 22403225, delete 22403343, find 6959339/9675898
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: Total swap = 4194300kB
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: 1048471 pages RAM
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: 40804 pages reserved
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: 0 pages cma reserved
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: 0 pages hwpoisoned
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: Tasks state (memory values in pages):
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    428]     0   428      620      158    45056       31             0 none
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    434]     0   434    30610      540   327680      444             0 systemd-journal
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    617]     0   617    70020     4471   102400        0         -1000 multipathd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    670]   100   670    23004      600    81920      254             0 systemd-timesyn
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    699]   101   699     4465      745    73728      239             0 systemd-network
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    700]   102   700     5167      740    86016      310             0 systemd-resolve
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    733]     0   733     5228      553    57344      334         -1000 systemd-udevd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    823]     0   823    59380      461    90112      319             0 accounts-daemon
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    824]   119   824     2118      598    57344      109             0 avahi-daemon
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    833]     0   833    78334      693   110592      427             0 ModemManager
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    839]     0   839     7609      806    94208     1970             0 networkd-dispat
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    847]     0   847    20462      635    65536       95             0 irqbalance
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    855]   105   855     2150      715    57344      402          -900 dbus-daemon
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    857]   103   857    56644      581    81920      334             0 rsyslogd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    859]     0   859    84027      547   147456      668             0 NetworkManager
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    862]     0   862     4121      648    69632      279             0 systemd-logind
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    867]     0   867     3404      655    73728      153             0 wpa_supplicant
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    871]     0   871   213215        0   245760     4151          -900 snapd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    876]   119   876     2087        0    57344       79             0 avahi-daemon
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    888]     0   888    58574      677    98304      608             0 polkitd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    904]     0   904     6987      614    90112     3087             0 supervisord
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    911]     0   911    63175      776   118784     2386             0 fail2ban-server
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    980]   111   980    62257      683   172032      543          -900 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    981]   111   981    53890      660   151552      544          -900 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    995]   111   995    53921      346   147456      531             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    996]   111   996    53924      203   147456      535             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    997]   111   997    53890      406   135168      522             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    998]   111   998    54032      295   147456      627             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [    999]   111   999    17653      391   118784      547             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1000]   111  1000    53996      296   135168      593             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1002]   111  1002    62286      268   163840      565             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1003]   111  1003    62291      355   159744      549             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1004]   111  1004    62257      228   151552      550             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1005]   111  1005    62398       24   163840      622             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1006]   111  1006    26021      222   135168      584             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1007]   111  1007    62357      325   159744      599             0 postgres
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1022]     0  1022    27362      756   110592     2027             0 unattended-upgr
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1085]     0  1085     2120      527    53248       88             0 cron
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1094]   997  1094   177359      110   172032     1816          -900 do-agent
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1116]     0  1116      934      529    45056       52             0 atd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1117]     0  1117     3007      548    69632      226         -1000 sshd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1137]     0  1137     1836      383    45056       35             0 agetty
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1145]     0  1145    59620      699    94208      286             0 gdm3
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1157]     0  1157    56650      495   180224     1746             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1210]   124  1210     4637      598    86016      473             0 systemd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1223]   124  1223    25703        0    98304      728             0 (sd-pam)
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1306]     0  1306   153404      475  1642496     6158             0 PM2 v3.5.1: God
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   1341]   115  1341    38218      595    61440       91             0 rtkit-daemon
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3088]     0  3088    41380      685    90112      327             0 gdm-session-wor
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3090]   124  3090     1908      703    61440      224             0 dbus-daemon
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3095]   124  3095    40756      601    90112      176             0 gdm-x-session
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3097]   124  3097    90488      873   315392     3139             0 Xorg
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3102]     0  3102     3317      652    65536      320             0 sshd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3107]   124  3107    65514      735   122880      431             0 gnome-session-b
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3111]   124  3111    76309      425    90112      187             0 at-spi-bus-laun
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3116]   124  3116     1800      685    49152      116             0 dbus-daemon
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3126]   124  3126   201188      766   155648      521             0 pulseaudio
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3130]   124  3130    22267      411    69632      116             0 gnome-session-c
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3138]   124  3138   120882      796   155648      576             0 gnome-session-b
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3146]   124  3146   637230      941   692224    19630             0 gnome-shell
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3223]     0  3223    62757      619    98304      341             0 upowerd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3233]   124  3233   130603      543   114688      357             0 ibus-daemon
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3240]   124  3240    58779      400    86016      177             0 ibus-dconf
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3243]   124  3243    47814      722   143360     1208             0 ibus-x11
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3246]   124  3246    58743      454    86016      165             0 ibus-portal
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3260]   124  3260    61735      672   114688      356             0 gsd-print-notif
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3261]   124  3261   170155      787   188416     1409             0 gsd-media-keys
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3262]   124  3262    79412      702   110592      276             0 gsd-sound
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3263]   124  3263    84652      775   155648     1254             0 gsd-wacom
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3264]   124  3264    84741      708   163840     1305             0 gsd-keyboard
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3265]   124  3265    78488      596   102400      265             0 gsd-smartcard
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3266]   124  3266   103430      682   163840     1257             0 gsd-color
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3269]   124  3269   114045      540   118784      223             0 gsd-rfkill
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3271]   124  3271    78231      508   102400      261             0 gsd-wwan
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3272]   124  3272    84701      678   167936     1310             0 gsd-xsettings
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3273]   124  3273    77158      493    98304      188             0 gsd-a11y-settin
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3274]   124  3274   103344      646   172032     1326             0 gsd-power
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3302]   124  3302    40654      552    81920      195             0 at-spi2-registr
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3308]   124  3308    39017      485    65536      147             0 dconf-service
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3314]   124  3314    85578      709   155648      493             0 gsd-printer
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3344]   122  3344    61187      831   110592     1157             0 colord
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3364]     0  3364     4572      535    81920      406             0 systemd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3365]     0  3365    25649        1    98304      735             0 (sd-pam)
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3383]     0  3383   213441      675   212992     2830             0 rygel
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3391]   124  3391    40324      392    73728      177             0 ibus-engine-sim
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3400]     0  3400     1768      596    57344      101             0 dbus-daemon
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   3522]     0  3522     2542      491    53248      462             0 bash
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  14988]     0 14988    70566      763   294912      209             0 journalctl
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  14989]     0 14989     1960      440    57344      148             0 pager
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  28357]     0 28357     3317      475    61440      292             0 sshd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  28429]     0 28429     2542      449    61440      470             0 bash
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  28454]     0 28454     5126      611    81920      317             0 mysql
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   9543]    33  9543    58288      577   229376     2943             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   9558]     0  9558     2243      743    61440      156             0 htop
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   9583]    33  9583    57497     1483   208896     1991             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   9587]    33  9587    57534     1427   208896     2015             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [   9653]    33  9653    58303      525   229376     2957             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10009]    33 10009    57517      390   208896     2764             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10034]     0 10034     2272      503    53248      326             0 nano
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10061]   110 10061  2148850   917687 15069184   916396             0 mysqld
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10107]     0 10107    26705     1324   188416     4057             0 php
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10108]     0 10108    26705     1321   200704     4059             0 php
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10109]     0 10109    26705     1227   184320     4052             0 php
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10110]     0 10110    26705     1132   196608     4060             0 php
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10111]     0 10111    26705     1221   196608     4075             0 php
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10112]     0 10112    26705     1209   192512     4066             0 php
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10113]     0 10113    26705     1210   188416     4052             0 php
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10114]     0 10114    26705     1065   192512     4054             0 php
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10188]    33 10188    57517      588   204800     2860             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10189]    33 10189    57524      368   208896     2786             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10216]    33 10216    57543      658   208896     2799             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10219]    33 10219    57529     1549   204800     1927             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10221]    33 10221    57496      344   204800     2686             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10222]    33 10222    57496     1737   204800     1704             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10223]     0 10223     3240      609    69632      274             0 sshd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10224]   108 10224     3007      316    65536      224             0 sshd
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10261]    33 10261    56981      930   200704     2011             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: [  10264]     0 10264    56654      375   163840     1583             0 apache2
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/system.slice/mysql.service,task=mysqld,pid=10061,uid=110
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 10061 (mysqld) total-vm:8595400kB, anon-rss:3670748kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 10061 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Oct 24 10:56:29 mydata systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

[image: mysqld using up all memory]

Comment: You should describe the workload. Which processes are hogging memory? What are they doing?

Comment: It looks like you were out of Swap space on the  journactl  report posted. Consider doubling your swap space limit.  Please post TEXT results of SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; so we can see what is hanging around and for how long.